# Captchas on RSS Reader?

Tags: rss, feed, aggregator

This question is coming from a non-technical person.  I have asked a team to build a sort of RSS reader.  In essence, its a news aggregator.  What we had in mind at first was to source news directly from specific sources: ft.com, reuters.com, and bloomberg.com.

Now, the development team has proposed a certain way of doing it (because it'll be easier)... which is to use news.google.com and return whatever is the result.  Now I know this has questionable legality and we are not really that comfortable with that fact, but while the legal department is checking that.. we have proceeded working with a prototype.

Now comes the technical problem... because the method was actually simulating search via news.google.com, after a period of time it returns a captcha.  I'm suspicious that its because the method was **SEARCHING WITH RESULTS SHOWN AS RSS** as opposed to an outright **RSS**... however the dev team says RSS is exactly the same thing... and that it will give captcha as well.

I have my doubts.  If thats the case, how have the other news aggregator sites done their compilation of feeds from different sources?

For your reference, here is the same of the URL that eventually gives the CAPTCHA
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?hl=en&gl=sg&as_qdr=a&authuser=0&q=dbs+bank+singapore&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=963&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

Answer (score 2):

"Searching" is usually behind a captcha because it is very resource intensive, thus they do everything they can to prevent bots from searching. A normal RSS feed is the opposite of resource intensive. To summarize: normal RSS feeds will probably not trigger CAPTCHA's.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google declared their News API deprecated as of May 26, 2011, maybe using [NewsCred](http://www.newscred.com/) as suggested in this group post http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/news/RBRH8pihQJI could be an option for your commercial use.